# jQuery onclick not sending data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why am I getting the following error below:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'data'`

**HTML:**

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'main post', 'onsubmit' => 'validateModules(event)', 'dataid' => $moviesparx_website_id); echo form_open("admin/websites/{$website_id}/page/op/{$action}/{$id}", $attributes); ?>

    <ul style="width: 25%; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; padding-right:10px;" class="postForm">
        <li>
            <input style="width:100%;" placeholder="Page Title" id="post_title" name="post_title" onclick="urlCheck()" dataid="<?php echo website_id;?> type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('post_title', $post['post_title']); ?>" />
            <?php echo form_error('post_title'); ?>
        </li>
```

**JS:**

```
function urlCheck()
{
      var id = self.data("id");

        $(".postForm").on('click', '#post_title', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           url      : '<?=base_url()?>/page/op',
           data     : { post_title : $("#post_title").val(), 'website_id' : id },
           type     : 'POST',
           success  : function(resp){
                alert( resp );
           },
           error    : function(resp){
                console.log("Error in ajax request");
           }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Is the problem that the click event handler is never called, or that the ajax request is returning something unexpected? Also, it may be more helpful to post the generated HTML, JS instead of the server side.

Comment: @makla Thanks - its because its never being called if I could solve this I should be sweet with the serverside "info"

Comment: The problem is line 3 of the JS snippet. It does not appear that 'self' is a jQuery element. Therefore .data() does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function urlCheck() {
    var id = self.data("id");

    $(".postForm").on('click', '#post_title', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url()?>/page/op',
            data: {
                post_title: $("#post_title").val(),
                    'website_id': id
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (resp) {
                alert(resp);
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log("Error in ajax request");
            }
        });
    });
}

urlCheck(); <-- did you add this line ?
```

Comment: Yes I did - my issue is that its never being called

Comment: Thanks I have changed the question as I worked that out :) you able to help?

Comment: Correct but why if its set in the html as `dataid`?

Comment: Please see html as I have changed it so the `dataid` is with the input.  I have also tried `var id = $(this).data("id");` but I am getting undefined

Comment: @JessMcKenzie, shouldn't it be `data-id`, not `dataid`? `dataid` is not a valid data attribute.